# Why the hive archive not support EXTERNAL_TABLE?

Tags: hive, external, archive

At present, out tables are **EXTERNAL_TABLE**, and there is a large amount of metadata information in NameNode, so I need to do archive to reduce the information, but hive archive is only support MANAGED_TABLE。

Can someone explain why archives don't support **EXTERNAL_TABLE**?

Is there any downside if I changed the code this way?

```
if (!(tbl.getTableType() == TableType.MANAGED_TABLE || tbl.getTableType() == TableType.EXTERNAL_TABLE))
{
    throw new HiveException("ARCHIVE can only be performed on managed tables");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to archive the meta data of external tables? Just to reduce the information? If you have the external tables in hive and you are doing this then this is not right. If you have the tables in hive then the meta data should not be deleted.
 In hive if you drop an external table then the meta data will also automatically delete. If you drop a managed table both data and meta data get delete
if you drop an external table only  meta data get  delete

Comment: Your missing the point. They're not wanting to Archive the meta data they're wanting to archive the files under the Hive External Table to reduce the number of small files the Name Node has to track. I actually have the same question as I'm trying to reduce the number of files we're storing.

Comment: For reducing the number of  small file archiving not better option I guess. You can simply set the parameters for this before running the insert queries. Below are few examples you can set according to your requirement.                    "set hive.merge.mapfiles=true;
set hive.merge.mapredfiles=true;
set hive.merge.smallfiles.avgsize=104857600;
set hive.merge.size.per.task=209715200;
set mapred.max.split.size=681574400;
set mapred.min.split.size=681574400;"